# Lord Buddha's Noble values

Tags: reference-request

We all know the famous nine values of Lord Buddha that we often recite when worshiping Lord Buddha. But i've heard the extended versions of those 9 values. Can someone point me a source to learn them?

Answer (score 2):

The qualities of the Buddha Dhamma and Sangha is found in the [Dhajagga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/15.5-Dhajagga-S-s11.3-piya.pdf), [Velu,dvāreyya Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.5-Veludvareyya-S-s55.7-piya.pdf) this might be a good starting point to study the qualities. Also [Buddhânussati](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/15.7-Buddhanussati-piya.pdf) by Piya Tan has more discussion including that of the the Mahayana parallels. The 10 Characteristics discussed in the Wikipedia article [Buddhahood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhahood) seas to be the Mahayana point of view. A more comprehensive book written in the subject is Suwisi Maha Gunaya by [Rerukane Chandawimala Thero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rerukane_Chandawimala_Thero) would be a the best starting point for a for some one who knows Sinhala. A similar book perhap not this extensive in English would be [Manual of Excellent Man: Uttamapurisa Dipani](http://www.holybooks.com/a-manual-of-the-excellent-man-by-ledi-sayadaw/) by [Ledi Sayadaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledi_Sayadaw)

Comment: Thank you Suminda, i wanted this to do an article on my blog and use for my knowledge as well. I share that good karma with you. Namo Buddhaya!

Comment: Nice to know it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Google returns many results (with explanations, for example [this one](http://www.tbsa.org/articles/BuddhaQualities.html) or [this one](http://www.urbandharma.org/pdf/PDF_BuddhismCourse/17_%20Recollection%20of%20the%20Buddha,%20Dhamma%20&%20Sangha.pdf)), if you search for [buddha nine characteristics](https://www.google.fr/search?q=buddha%20nine%20characteristics) (or 'qualities' or 'virtues'), rather than nine 'values'.

Or Wikipedia mentions [10 characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhahood#Ten_characteristics_of_a_Buddha).

Comment: Thank you chris, i wanted this to do an article on my blog and use for my knowledge as well. I share that good karma with you. Namo Buddhaya!